# WP LayerSlide counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

In wordpress how do I in LayerSlide put a counter? Here was an example counter that I tried to use below:

```
<p>team number <span id="lines">0</span> </p>
$('#lines').animateNumber({ number: 165 }); )
```

I already tried to put this code in here, but doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: What's exactly you want? Count number of sliders right? xD